# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb C$ is a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm not entirely sure that I understand the concept of fields fully so I'll give you the question and then I'll let you pick my brain and tell me if my logic is correct.

Please note: I'm not just asking a question that I already know the answer to. I want you to tell me if I'm missing anything so I can get rid of my doubt.

Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb C$ is a field?

$A) \left\{ 2x+1: x \in \mathbb Z \right\},$

$B) \left\{ 2x: x \in \mathbb Z \right\},$

$C) \left\{ x^3: x \in \mathbb R \right\},$

$D) \left\{ z \in \mathbb C: |z| =1 \right\},$

$E) \text { None of the above.}$

So I don't think A & B can be fields because since $x \in \mathbb Z$, only integers form part of the set. This can't be a field because say $x=2$ then in A, $5$ will be part of the set but $\frac{1}{5}$ won't be and there's a condition that says there must be an inverse that is also part of the set.

Now I think C is correct because I think it satisfies all the conditions and in D, the only 2 elements of this set are 1 and -1 which satisfy all of the conditions except for the one that says there must be $0 \in F$ such that $x+0=x$ for all $x \in F$

Comment: Your reasoning is correct for A). *Similar* reasoning will hold for B), but you should be more explicit. For C), you need to be more explicit, it is not "obvious" that it forms a field. For D) you are correct, but for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @David Wheeler please help me out on how to be more explicit and correct my reasoning. Or at least explain why it's wrong

Comment: Was I right that -1 and 1 are the only elements in D?

Comment: An element in D) not of the form you think it is, consider $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. D) is, in fact, closed under multiplication, but NOT addition- $1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ does not have modulus 1, for example.

Comment: But how is $|\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}| = 1$. This is why I feel like I'm missing something fundamental?

Comment: By definition, in the complex numbers, for $z = a+ib$ we have $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ (the Euclidean length of the vector $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb R^2$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21750/discussion-between-david-wheeler-and-stephancasey).